# How to revert the last 2 commits done on Git

Tags: git, git-revert

I have a situation here where there are 2 commits done by another collaborator which seems to be the wrong files. I am the owner of the repository and would like to revert those 2 commits done by the other collaborator. From my terminal, I tried the following.

`git log -2` and it just says the last 2 commits which I did. I want to know how I can reset the last 2 commits and change the HEAD to the commit before those 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I undo the last commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-last-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `git revert`:

```
git revert A^..B
```

where `A` is hash of the first of the two commits to be reverted and `B` is the hash of the second commit.  This approach will work even if other commits have been made on the remote branch since the two commits were made.

If this branch were not shared with anyone you could also use

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

But beware of using `git reset --hard` on a publicly shared branch.  For a shared branch, it is much safer to use `git revert` as described above.

Comment: A^ should be replaced by the commit hash ?

Comment: @RaMaJ Yes, replace `A` and `B` with the commit hashes for the first and second commits.

Comment: `A` is an older commit and `B` is a newer commit, right? Just making sure I get the orders =)

Comment: I've used `git reset` then what? if i do `git log` i can still see those commits

Comment: Yes, a revert commit is added which reverses both of those commit's diffs.

Answer (score 10):

Try this but be sure of what you want to do

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

`git reset --hard` is an irreversible change. Also it may be a good time to learn about `git reset --hard/--soft/ --mixed`

[image]

I would also suggest going through [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Answer (score 6):

Just reset it to the commit hash that was prior to the 2 commits:

```
git reset <commit-hash>
```

This will delete the commits after `commit-hash` and bring the changes to your workspace. If you don't want the changes you can pass a `--hard` option.